# GetCurPage в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Как в битриксе перечислить страницы в конструкции:

```
if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() != '/page-name/'):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только добавляя условия через логический оператор

```
if (($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() != '/page-name/') && ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() != '/page-name-2/')) {
```